# resetting AUTO_INCREMENT doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I have a table called Person in MySQL. There is a column `id` which has `UNIQUE` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` property and also a primary key. I want to reset the counter of `id` so that it restarts from 1. I used the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE Person AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

But after I applied this change, the `id` still starts from my last position (130), not from 1. So why this resetting doesn't work?

Comment: Does the table have data in it that needs to maintain it's existing IDs or is it empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TRUNCATE TABLE` as this will reset the autoincrement

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html)...
From MySQL 5.0.13 on, the AUTO_INCREMENT counter is reset to zero by TRUNCATE TABLE, regardless of whether there is a foreign key constraint.)

Comment: Thanks. This solution works. So the ALTER TABLE approach to reset the counter is obsolete?

Comment: The previous presence of rows doesn't change the auto increment start seed so when you are trying to alter the table and set it to 1 you are assigning a property it already has so it simply has no effect.  There is a difference between the seed (the number you specify for auto increment to start from) and the position/counter (determined by rows inserted).

Comment: Thanks Steph for clarifying this.